# Listening to successful login with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to perform several actions when a **User** successfully logs in to my app, this actions need some **User** data as parameters, so is there a way to *listen* to successful logins with Spring Security 3.0.x? Or any other way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: AuthenticationSuccessHandler is a good approach if you want to handle something sequentially right after a successful login. Another way to get a hold of that event is through an ApplicationListener: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html)

```
<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"/>
```

You can get the username from the Authentication (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) that is passed to onAuthenticationSuccess() and then look up the other user info from there.