# How to check that BadCredentialsException is not thrown in loadUserByUsername

Tags: spring, spring-security

i am authenticating my users with UserDetailsService:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">          
      <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
         <password-encoder hash="sha"/>             
      </authentication-provider>   
    </authentication-manager>
```

userDetailsService class:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

User user = null;
    try {
        user = userService.getUserByUsername(username);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


   if (user.isForceChangePass()) {
        MyForcePasswordChangeException bad = new MyForcePasswordChangeException(
                "Password is not valid, and it must be changed!");
        throw bad;
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

after getting username i check for ForceChangePass indicator and if it's true i through my own exception which in turns lands user to loginFailureHandler (despite password is correct or not) i want in the loginFailureHandler to check if my exception is thrown in case of login success only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loadUserByUsername()` is not suppose to check credentials, it should only load `UserDetails` object (having `getPassword()` method) or throw `UsernameNotFoundException`.

If you want to check whether the user successfully authenticated or not, have a look at [Listening to successful login with Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366837):

```
<form-login 
  authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
  authentication-failure-url="authenticationFailureHandler"/>
```

You must implement [`AuthenticationSuccessHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) and [`AuthenticationFailureHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationFailureHandler.html).

Alternatively consider subclassing `BasicAuthenticationFilter` and override `onSuccessfulAuthentication()` and `onUnsuccessfulAuthentication()`.

Comment: i added more details for my question.

Comment: @fresh_dev: what about checking `ForceChangePass` in `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and if set, invalidate the session and redirect the user to change password page? You have all the pieces in place (`Authentication`, request and response)